# Kivy scatterLayout revert to original size

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

My apologies if this is a dumb question.

I am trying to make a zoom-able interface but I want it to reset it's self after a while. I managed to make it zoom-able using a scatterLayout but I can't get it to revert back to its original size after that, unless the user zooms back out himself. 
Any way to reset my scatterLayout to its original size after I zoom in on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, well an answer.

I overwrite the on_touch_up event and use the transform ObjectProperty of the Scatter widget with a matrix of 1,1,1 like so

```
from kivy.graphics.transformation import Matrix
def on_touch_up(self, touch):
trans = Matrix().scale(1, 1, 1)
self.ids['myScat'].transform=trans
```